'Table data cannot be migrated, source table is empty' in Azure SQL migration wizard
I'm trying to use either the Azure Data Studio SQL Migration Wizard or the Azure SQL Database Offline Wizard to migrate local databases to Azure SQL databases.
My databases have tables that at times are empty, but both wizards are failing to migrate them because of this, which I don't understand:

Table data cannot be migrated, source table is empty.



It is essential the tables and their respective relationships aren't left behind as they are integral to the application!  I've searched for solutions but can't find anything matching these error messages.
Can anyone please offer an explanation of why the wizards won't process empty tables, and if there's a workaround?

Can't you migrate the table individually and manually? It's just a CREATE TABLE statement, right?

Isn't it enough to do: "missing schema" and just uncheck the empty tables in the "migrate data" section?

@Dai there are lots of relationships, indexes, etc. that I don't trust will be reliably migrated, so am not comfortable with a partial migration.  I've got 22 databases to migrate so this approach will get too complex.

@siggemannen that's what I thought, but the table selection checkbox is disabled even with "missing schema" enabled.

@EvilDr I assume by "relationship"  you mean "foreign-key constraint"; the CREATE TABLE statement will necessarily include all member constraints. That said, you should first migrate only schema/DDL without any data - it's curious that this migration tool you're using won't migrate empty tables, because other tooling (like SSDT) definitely will.

@Dai agreed!  I'm trying not to rant but need a reliable migration strategy!  SSDT did work for us but took hours for a 5GB database, so I'm looking for a faster option.

@EvilDr I wouldn't recommend using SSDT to move data around - only for schema changes. I recommend you use SSIS to migrate data after using SSDT to update/redeploy the schema.

Well, doesn't that means that you can just continue and it will work? Since you only need schema. Perhaps azure d s is not prepared for this kind of scenario

The solution was to avoid the migration wizard entirely and do the whole thing in SSMS. I don't believe this tool has been properly developed or tested given the number of issues people face with frozen progress that they get billed for.
By using the SSMS "Export Data Tier Application" functionality and saving as a .BACPAC file, I was then able to also use SSMS to connect to the destination server and "Import Data-tier Application".
Hint: If you do this, SQL Azure needs a high amount of computing power to get the job done.  Therefore I commissioned the database as GEN5_80 (price is enormous per month, but you scale it back down in the Azure portal as soon as the job finishes).  My 5GB database took about 10 minutes to migrate.
